# Marker direction in MapBox android

Tags: android, mapbox

I am creating android app which shows the location of a bus in map using mapbox sdk.
I want to rotate the marker based on location just like Uber app does.
How could i achieve this?

Code:

```
IconFactory iconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(navigationActivity.this);
    Drawable iconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(navigationActivity.this, R.drawable.bus);
    Icon icon = iconFactory.fromDrawable(iconDrawable);
    map.clear();
    CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(lat,lon)) // Sets the new camera position
            .zoom(16) // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(180) // Rotate the camera
            .tilt(30) // Set the camera tilt
            .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(position), 7000);
    final Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat,lon))
            .title("You!")
            .snippet("YOu are Currently here."));
    marker.setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: You did not mention what problem you are facing! Already you have bearing and tilt functions implemented in code

Comment: Yeah when the map is loaded, it will animate and rotate.. But when another location comes in another horizonatal road, the bus icon will go to that road but in vertical direction which how the image of marker is.. I need it to align horizontally @Stallion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [an example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/labs/SpaceStationLocationActivity.java) which does just what your asking for except instead of a bus, it tracks the International Space Station in realtime. Computation of the heading is done using Turf and the Mapbox Android Services SDK but if you only need that single method, you can just copy the method from the library. Here's the important code from the example I mentioned above:

```
// Make sure you are using marker views so you can update the rotation.
marker.setRotation((float) computeHeading(marker.getPosition(), position));

...

public static double computeHeading(LatLng from, LatLng to) {
// Compute bearing/heading using Turf and return the value.
    return TurfMeasurement.bearing(
        Position.fromCoordinates(from.getLongitude(), from.getLatitude()),
        Position.fromCoordinates(to.getLongitude(), to.getLatitude())
    );
}
```

You can also use this method which I previously used before Turf:

```
// Returns the heading from one LatLng to another LatLng. Headings are. Expressed in degrees
// clockwise from North within the range [-180,180). The math for this method came from
// http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Crs I only converted it to Java.
public static double computeHeading(LatLng from, LatLng to) {
    double fromLat = Math.toRadians(from.getLatitude());
    double fromLng = Math.toRadians(from.getLongitude());
    double toLat = Math.toRadians(to.getLatitude());
    double toLng = Math.toRadians(to.getLongitude());
    double dLng = toLng - fromLng;
    double heading = Math.atan2(Math.sin(dLng) * Math.cos(toLat),
            Math.cos(fromLat) * Math.sin(toLat) - Math.sin(fromLat) * Math.cos(toLat) * Math.cos(dLng));
    return (Math.toDegrees(heading) >= -180 && Math.toDegrees(heading) < 180) ?
            Math.toDegrees(heading) : ((((Math.toDegrees(heading) + 180) % 360) + 360) % 360 + -180);
}
```

Comment: i tried the second function still its does not point to the direction..

Comment: Hey my mistake, Both from and to i given same cordinates.. Now it works.. But i another issue i face here now is each time when marker changes it from the marker rotates even if it in same direction..

Comment: It shouldn't be, rotating every single time. The only issue with the code above is it will always rotate the marker clockwise, even if rotating counter-clockwise would be shorter. A fix for this would be a if check to determine which direction to rotate in.

Comment: Yeah, I finaly found a work around where instead of marker i rotated the map,so that map wont rotate always unless there is a direction change.. Anyway thanks.